# How do I pick up logs I have knocked over?

Tags: kirby-triple-deluxe

Twice I now in Hypernova mode I have used a wrecking ball to knock down a tree and a log always falls over some sort of useful item, even as it also opens up a new area. How can I move the log to get what is underneath?

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually move these - when they fall down instead of breaking completely apart, it is because you did not hit them with enough force, and your only option is to leave the area (if possible) and come back to try again.